# If $X \sim \text{Exp}(1)$, show that $\sqrt X$ follows a Rayleigh distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a task to show that if $$X  \sim \text{Exp}(1)$$ then $$\sqrt X \sim \mathrm{Rayleigh}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)$$

How do I start from here?

For $X\sim$ exponential, I know that the pdf is defined as
$$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$
and for Rayleigh
$$f_X(x) = \frac{x}{\lambda ^2} e^{\frac{-(\lambda x)^2}{2}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I start?

Notice that $Y = \sqrt X$ is one to one over the possible values of $X$. Hence you can you use the one to one transformation; $X = Y^2$, and so
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{f_X(y^2)}{\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x = y^2}}.$$

Otherwise, you can use the cdf method,
$$P(Y\leq y) = P(\sqrt X\leq y) = P(X\leq y^2).$$

Comment: Thanks, 1one to one transformation was the key! Didn't know about that.

Comment: You can use the cdf approach to. But remember, it gives the cdf. So to get the desired density, you take the derivative of the cdf. Good luck.